# Convert string to tuple in python

Tags: python

Pretty simply question but giving me some trouble:

I have

```
 "('A', 'Open')" # type = str
```

and would like:

```
 ('A','Open') # type = tuple
```

Have tried using .split(), and just converting the whole thing to tuple(str) with no success.

Comment: where does this `"('A', 'Open')"` come from?

Comment: `import ast; my_tuple = ast.literal_eval(my_string)`

Comment: @L3viathan inbuilt `eval()` itself can do it, no need for external lib.

Comment: @buran from a feather file, the read_dataframe outputs the multiindex in a weird fashion (eg. above)

Comment: @meW thanks ... did not know about this .. will take a read

Comment: @meW provide your comment as answer

Comment: @meW, don't suggest use of `eval`, that is potentially dangerous without explicit warning.

Comment: @buran so what is your say on this question?

Comment: @prashantrana this question is too generic, there must be a duplicate somewhere out there with proper explanation.

Comment: @meW, the proper way is suggested by L3viathan. And also I think that OP has problem with the proper use of multi index in pandas - that's why I asked where it comes from. In my opinion that is example of [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: @meW you are right , found it is duplicate question

Comment: @buran that's correct, even I prefer using `ast.literal_eval()` in most cases and gave the first comment edit the same.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve this, both parse the string as Python code.

The seemingly easier option is to use [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

The slightly more complicated, but better, option is to use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

In [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval) everything has already been said why the latter is almost always what you really want. Note that even the official documentation of `eval` says that you should use `ast.literal_eval` instead.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is _slightly more complicated_ than `eval`, how so?

Comment: @vishes_shell: You need to add an import (albeit from the standard library). I did not say it was a lot more complicated... It might also be slightly slower in evaluating the string, since it first performs some checks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import re

m_s = "('A', 'Open')"
patt = r"\w+"
print(tuple(re.findall(patt, m_s)))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using regular expressions ?

```
In [1686]: x
Out[1686]: '(mono)'

In [1687]: tuple(re.findall(r'[\w]+', x))
Out[1687]: ('mono',)

In [1688]: x = '(mono), (tono), (us)'

In [1689]: tuple(re.findall(r'[\w]+', x))
Out[1689]: ('mono', 'tono', 'us')

In [1690]: x = '(mono, tonous)'

In [1691]: tuple(re.findall(r'[\w]+', x))
Out[1691]: ('mono', 'tonous')
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest is do

```
eval("('A','Open')") #will return type as tuple
```

eval() evaluates and executes string as python expression